# How to convert LPCWSTR to LPWSTR

Tags: c++

How can I convert  LPCWSTR to LPWSTR.

In one method I am getting an argument type as **LPCWSTR**. This parameter(LPCWSTR) has to be passed to another method of argument type **LPWSTR**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LPCWSTR is a pointer to a const string buffer. LPWSTR is a pointer to a non-const string buffer. Just create a new array of wchar_t and copy the contents of the LPCWSTR to it and use it in the function taking a LPWSTR.

Answer (score 10):

Create a new string, copy the contents into it, and then call the function that expects a modifiable string:

```
LPCWSTR str = L"bar";
std::wstring tempStr(str); 
foo(&tempStr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a copy of the string, and pass a pointer to the copy. An LPCWSTR i a pointer to a `const`, which means the content can't be modified. An LPWSTR is a pointer to non-const, meaning it may modify the content, so you need to make a copy it can modify before you can use that function.

Comment: @ Jerry, in my requirement, no need to change the paratmeter content

Comment: @kanden: if the function doesn't modify the string, then change its parameter to LPCWSTR. Having done this, you'll be able to pass the existing LPCWSTR directly, with no conversion needed.