# C26492 Don't use `const_cast` to cast away const or volatile (type.3)

Tags: visual-c++, c-strings, code-analysis

Here is an interesting discussion about not using [`const_cast`](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/04/26/dont-cast-away-const-in-cpp.aspx) where you are encouraged to use `mutable`.

Here is my code:

```
MENUITEMINFO sInfo{};
sInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
sInfo.fMask = MIIM_STRING;
sInfo.dwTypeData = const_cast<TCHAR*>(strHostLabel.GetString());
SetMenuItemInfo(pMnuSwap->GetSafeHmenu(), SwapAssignment::Host, TRUE, &sInfo);
sInfo.dwTypeData = const_cast<TCHAR*>(strCoHostLabel.GetString());
SetMenuItemInfo(pMnuSwap->GetSafeHmenu(), SwapAssignment::Cohost, TRUE, &sInfo);
```

The code analysis is telling me:

> warning [C26492](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26492?view=msvc-160): Don't use `const_cast` to cast away const or volatile (type.3).

I understand that they are saying it is bad design to do this and that you can adjust a class to allow it to still be `const` but permit certain variables to be modifiable. Atleast, I understood that from the linked discussion.

But that does not apply in this context.

---

I saw the answers for this question ([How to convert LPCWSTR to LPWSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825951/how-to-convert-lpcwstr-to-lpwstr)) which implies copying the string to another one. Is there no simpler way?

- `sInfo.dwTypeData` is of type `LPWSTR`.
- `GetString` returns a `LPCWSTR`.

This was why I used `const_cast`. Is there another way to make this code analysis compatible without overcomplicating it?

My code compiles for both 32 bit and 64 bit. This is why I have historically used `TCHAR`.

Comment: Copying the string can be pretty simple.   `stdTstring hostLabel = strHostLabel.GetString(); sInfo.dwTypeData = &hostLabel[0];`  Assuming that you have a typedef named `stdTstring` (or pick your own name).

Comment: Since the structure is being passed to `SetMenuItemInfo`, the pointer will be used only to read the string, so the cast is safe. The compiler doesn't know this, though. (If you had passed it to `GetMenuItemInfo`, then it would be a different story.)

Comment: @RaymondChen So I should use `prama` to suppress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way, I believe, would be to use [GetBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=msvc-160#getbuffer).

At some point you will find a function that *really* needs non-const string :)