# How to I get the contents from a wchar_t array into a LPWSTR?

Tags: c++, string, constants, widechar

I found a very [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825951/), which gives the answer as:

> LPCWSTR is a pointer to a const string buffer. LPWSTR is a pointer to a non-const string buffer. Just create a new array of wchar_t and copy the contents of the LPCWSTR to it and use it in the function taking a LPWSTR.

I think I understand the first part - create a new array of `wchar_t` and copy the contents of the `LPCWSTR` to it.

```cpp
wstring wstrSrc(myString.begin(), myString.end());
const int lngth = sizeof(wstrSrc) / sizeof(int);
PCWSTR str2PCWSTR = wstrSrc.c_str();
const wchar_t* filepath[lngth]{ str2PCWSTR };
```

However, I am not sure how to do the second part - use it in the function taking a `LPWSTR`.

How do I use the contents of the `wchar_t` array in a `PWSTR`?

I tried searching for a clearer answer to the one I found, and tried, or made an effort to understand the suggestion.

I have not gotten any further than the code above.

Comment: `const int lngth = sizeof(wstrSrc) / sizeof(int);` makes no sense at all. The size of a `wstring` is constant and has nothing to do with the data contained in it. It has a `size()` member function for a reason.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], i.e. some code that is at least complete. At the moment, we don't know what `myString` is.

Comment: You don't. LPWSTR is a pointer to a string, not a string. This is one of those rare cases where you might need `const_cast<LPWSTR>(wstrSrc.c_str())`. After that forget const_cast exists again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the right answer is just `wstrSrc.data()`

Comment: Wherever it is that you want an `LPWSTR` just write `wstrSrc.data()` and the problem is solved. C++ strings and vectors are designed to work where pointers are needed. You are trying too hard and getting yourself very confused in the process.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks. Do I provide that code, in the original post?

Answer (score 2):

`LPWSTR` is an alias for `wchar_t*`. So if you have an array of `wchar_t` elements, you already have a `LPWSTR` (remember that arrays *decay* to pointers to their first element).

As for getting a `LPWSTR` from a `wstring` object, just get a pointer to its first element: `&wstrSrc[0]`. That will be a `wchar_t*`, which as said above is the same as `LPWSTR`. With later standards of C++ you can also use `wstrSrc.data()` to get the pointer.

If you want a pointer to constant string (i.e. `LPCWSTR`) then use `wstrSrc.c_str()`.

---

As for other problems `sizeof` returns the size of the *object* you pass to it, which in the case of `wstrSrc` will be the size of a `std::wstring` (assuming `wstring` is `std::wstring`). And the size of `std::wstring` is not the length of the string, as `std::wstring` only keeps a *pointer* to the actual string data.

To get the length in `wchar_t` elements from the string object use its `length` function: `wstrSrc.length()`.

Also note that on Windows using the MSVC compiler, `sizeof(wchar_t) != sizeof(int)`. On Windows using MSVC the size of `wchar_t` is currently `2` while the size of a 32-bit `int` is `4`.

Comment: `wstrSrc.data()` is a more understandable way to get a mutable pointer.

Comment: @MooingDuck only in C++17 and later, though.  `&wstrSrc[0]` is guaranteed to work fine in C++11 and C++14.  Before C++11, it is not *guaranteed* to work, but *usually does* in any sane implementation.

Comment: My problem was not being able to convert a string to PWSTR, I only am able to convert to PCWSTR, which does not work in LoadBitmapFromFile.

@MooingDuck your code solved the problem I was having.
I needed the PWSTR to drop in as the source file.
Not being able to correctly convert the string to PWSTR, LoadBitmapFromFile was failing.
It succeeded when I dropped wstrSrc.data() in there, as source. Thanks